# sed to delete undesirable dnsmasq conf file lines

Tags: sed, dnsmasq

I've learned a bit about sed so far reading questions on this - thanks everyone.  Feels like I'm close to what I want to achieve, but stuck at one bit.

I'm trying to check a dnsmasq blocklist file (oisd to be specific).  What I have so far:

```
'\|^address=/[[:alnum:]]|!d;\|/#$|!d'
```

What I'm trying to achieve:
delete any lines not starting with "address=/(must be followed by one alphanumeric character), (followed by any number of alphanumeric characters, this time allowing both . -), must end with /#

It's that middle bit I'm stuck on (followed by any number of alphanumeric characters, this time allowing both . -)

```
address=/test.com/#          - not deleted, as desired

address=/.com/#              - is deleted due to not being one alphanumeric char directly after address=/

address=/test.com/1.1.1.1    - is deleted due to not ending in /#

address=/test/&.com/#        - not currently deleted, but this is what I want to delete also
```

```
'\|^address=/[[:alnum:]]|!d;\|/#$|!d'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E '\~^address=/[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]/.]+#$~!d' input_file
address=/test.com/#
```

Comment: Hey wow, thankyou so much for the fast reply!  Especially for my first post here ever.

This one still let these through for example:

address=/test/com/#

address=/test.com#

but a quick tweak to yours seems to fix it. 

-E '\~^address=/[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:].-]+/#$~!d'

does this look right to you?

Comment: @Wizballs Yes, that looks correct if the intention is to only match when it ends with `/#` and is not nested.